# SQL Server multiple joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Can anyone explains what is the wrong with this query?

```
select A.*
   from GDPApplication A,
        (select top(e.ToDate) *
         from EducationalQualification e
         where e.Id = A.Id
         order by e.ToDate desc
       ) B left outer join
       EnglishTest eng on A.Id = eng.FKApplicationId
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: apart from the above comment, which is very good advice, would you care to define "wrong"? What problem is it giving you, exactly? What did you expect to happen, and what happens instead? P.S. We can't see your schema or data or your requirements, and we're not magic so we can't guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TOP` clause requires numeric parameter such as `TOP (1)` in order to fetch N.. no of rows from top position based on `ordering` defined

```
select A.*
from GDPApplication A cross apply (
         select top (1) e.ToDate,  *
         from EducationalQualification e
         where e.Id = A.Id
         order by e.ToDate desc
       ) B left outer join
       EnglishTest eng on A.Id = eng.FKApplicationId
```